# Why I got valid_index precondition violation in Eiffel?

Tags: eiffel, preconditions

I just simply test a push_at feature of container class(made by array, basically). I dont know which part of my code triggers this violation.

```
push_at (i: INTEGER; s: STRING)

    require
        valid_index: i  >= 1
    do
        container [i] := s

    end
```

In my tester

```
local
        con: CONTAINER

do
          create {CONTAINER}con.make
          con.push_at (1,"A")
          con.push_at (2,"B")

 Result := con.get(1) ~ "A" and con.get(2) ~ "B"
 check Result end
 end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's container [i]. When you create con, it will be empty (probably - you haven't shown us your code).
You precondition needs to reflect the precondition on con []. Which will in turn need to reflect the precondition on {ARRAY}.put, which you must be using to implement it. Your current precondition does not do that (it is rather arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

The underlying structure used as a storage for the elements does not automatically allocate memory for new elements. Some structures do that when the assigner command `container [i] := s` is executed. But this is not the case in the code you mention. Consequently, the index `i` used in this command is invalid, hence the precondition violation. If you look at the exception trace or the call stack, you'll see that the precondition violation occurs not in the feature `{CONTAINER}.puch_at`, but in `{ARRAY}.put` or similar, which – by coincidence and naming convention – uses the same precondition tag `valid_index`.

There are different ways to solve the issue:

1. Use a different structure for storage (the attribute `container` in your example), e.g. it could be `HASH_TABLE [STRING, INTEGER]`. Then it becomes possible to store elements at arbitrary indexes.
2. Make sure the storage is pre-allocated. If you know the range of possible indexes, then `container` can be initialized to use them all from the beginning. It can be created with `create container.make_filled ("", 1, N)`, where `N` is the maximum index. (I assume that `container` is of type `ARRAY [STRING]`.)
3. Add elements one-by-one. In this case the precondition of `push_at` should check whether the supplied index either exists or is adjacent to the previously allocated one:

   ```
   require
         valid_index: i >= 1
         existing_or_adjacent_index:
             container.valid_index (i) or else
             container.valid_index (i - 1)
   ```

   The code of `push_at` should be adapted to use the feature that will allocate a new index if the supplied one is beyond the range of allocated indexes:

   ```
   container.force (s, i)
   ```

Cosmetics: there is no need to repeat the type declaration in the creation instruction `create {CONTAINER} con.make` because the type of the variable `con` is `CONTAINER`. So, it's sufficient to use `create con.make`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to increment the container. Problem solved.